# Bulk update of only date and month in DATE column

Tags: oracle

I have a column with datatype as DATE in oracle. I want to update all the coumns with date and month as '01-JAN' and I don't want disturb the year.

For example:
Before update:

```
DATE
======
05-DEC-12
07-FEB-11
27-MAR-99
```

After update:

```
DATE
======
01-JAN-12
01-JAN-11
01-JAN-99
```

Can you please provide me the UPDATE query to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
update your_table set datecol = trunc(datecol,'yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update table 
set col = to_date('01-JAN'||to_char(col,'yy'),'dd-MON-yy')
```